# Quick question regarding wording of a homework question

Tags: plane-curves

Find the equation for the plane passing through the heads of the three given vectors

(2, 2, 0)

(−1, 2, 1)

(1, 1, 4)

Is this just another way of asking what is the plane passing through these points, or does "through the heads" mean something different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply ensure that all three points are on the plane. A point and two direction vectors are required to define a plane.

By stating "head of the three vectors", this implies that the vectors are coming from the origin (with the tail at 0,0,0). The "head" essentially represents a point on the plane.

Comment: Alright, so just to check the answer would be 2a - 2b + 6c - 24 = 0?

Comment: x+11y-3z-24=0, remember you need to be able to satisfy ALL of the three points

Comment: useful calculator with explanation at bottom http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223596129

Comment: the calculator is giving a different answer than what you said, could you walk me through the steps of how you are getting it?

Comment: my bad, answer's x+11y+3z-24=0, calculator is correct

Comment: first step: find any two direction vectors using the given three points. then, find the cross product of those direction vectors. then find the dot product of the cross product (found earlier) with a point on the plane (this is your D value). The coefficients of your cross product are your A, B, C respectively. The form is Ax + By + Cz - D = 0

Comment: Ah, thanks. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

It should just mean through the three points, although it does seem to be a rather bizarre way to phrase it.